# Deploying different versions of OSGI-application stack in the same container

Tags: architecture, osgi

I'm building an API which has a REST frontend and the whole stack contains almost 10 different bundles, and slowly growing. This works great so far.

In the long run I'm planning to have different versions of the API-stack (using OSGi versoning mechanism), accessible via the REST-frontend in the format of `/api/v2/path/to/resource` or something similar.

My first thought was just to deploy the whole stack for the new version, eg. install all my bundles. The new REST-bundle will add `/api/<version-number>` to jaxrs-server in blueprint and everything should work, but my concern is that there will be ALOT of bundles deployed in the long run. I'm sensing that I will lose the overall overview of installed bundles and so on.

Is there any way to separate my stacks in some way?
I don't want to install a new container for each version. I have looked a bit at Karaf's instances but will I be able to "append" to jaxrs-servers in the same way as if the bundles was installed in the same instance? Eg. access the REST-frontend on the same host, port etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that isolation is important. The OSGi Framework was only ever designed to host a single "application". If you deploy multiple applications to the same framework without isolation, you will get interference between the two, such as undesired sharing of packages and services.

For example, you could thoroughly test one application and find that it works. Then you thoroughly test a second application and find that it also works. Finally you deploy both of them into an OSGi framework and find that neither works! This is not good...

The subsystems spec does provide isolation but it is complex and the implementations immature. I would suggest simply instantiating multiple OSGi frameworks. This can be done easily within a single JVM, there are no static or singletons in OSGi that would prevent it. The basic code required to instantiate an OSGi framework is around 5-10 lines.

**UPDATE**: For detailed information on how to instantiate a new OSGi Framework, see my blog post ["How to Embed OSGi"](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any link to example how to instantiating OSGi? And could this be administrated with something like Felix Web Console?

Comment: @Marcus: I have added a link to my answer with some example code. As for administering this with Felix Web Console... no, that's not possible at the moment because Web Console only knows about a single OSGi Framework.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely go for some isolation between the versions.

Granted, the OSGi versioning is pretty powerful, but if you are planning to deploy lots of different versions of the same bundle, you better get all the wiring *exactly* right or you are going to run into very hard to debug problems. Also, you could possibly mess up an older version by deploying a newer version, which is (I guess) exactly what you want to prevent.

In Karaf the separation between instances might be a bit too heavy weight for you, as you can not easily share bundles between instances.

The OSGi standard addressing this is called subsystems, and this does allow you to do what you want, which is having different scoped sub applications that will share much of their code, like the http server.

This standard is pretty new, I don't think there is a mature implementation but I recommend taking a look at [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/). Virgo does not support subsystems (yet?) but Virgo has a notion of 'plans' which I think will serve your purpose.

Comment: Subsystem looks really promising, looking forward to try that when that time comes :) So what you recomend today is really running separate container instances or is there any other way to isolate my stacks?

Comment: The RI for Subsystems is part of Apache Aries. However there are no binary downloads available (as of 31 March 2013), it looks like you would have to build Aries from source.